# mysql - group by INTERVAL 1 HOUR (detecting suspicious bulk logins)

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I want to find out which users log in the most in a one hour window. I record all activity in a table called `user_activity`, which has `event_class`, `timestamp` and `user_id` columns (others exist but aren't significant). When a user logs in, a `LOGIN` event class is written along with the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` against their `user_id`.

The server runs competitive university event signups and student CAPTCHA solvers (Python/OpenCV2...) have been caught in the past when I saw hundreds of `login` events in a matter of an hour or so for one user (**see below**). I made a script to temporarily ban users logging in more than 5 times in the last ten minutes, which is simple enough.

I now want to search historic records to see the total count per user of logins per one hour window. In pseudo-speak: "`select each user_id from user_activity and group by total logins per last interval 1 hour`" so I can quickly see which users and IP addresses (not shown) login rapidly. Can this be done?

*Sample of "Sean"'s last 30 logins before we banned him*

`+---------+-------------+---------------------+
| user_id | event_class | timestamp           |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 21:46:20 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:48:55 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:45:01 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:43:41 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:42:06 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:37:19 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:32:31 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:27:17 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:26:21 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:25:44 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:24:08 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:20:44 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 20:16:59 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 18:23:44 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 13:01:14 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 12:55:12 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-05-01 12:47:58 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 16:09:51 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:38:22 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:37:31 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:36:20 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:35:33 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:34:08 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:31:46 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:24:33 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:23:22 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:20:27 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:09:49 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:05:59 |
|     617 | LOGIN       | 2018-04-30 15:00:03 |
+---------+-------------+---------------------+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can simply select the data you need and group by it like this:

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    CONCAT(DATE(`timestamp`), ' ', HOUR(`timestamp`)) AS datehour,
    COUNT(1) AS logins
FROM user_activity
WHERE event_class = 'LOGIN'
GROUP BY user_id, datehour
HAVING logins > 5
```

Here we should see a row for each user who logged in more than 5 times during each hour.  The only caveat here is that this is *per clock hour* so if they log in 3 times at 10:59pm and 3 more times at 11:01pm they wouldn't have more than 3 attempts during any particular hour.

Comment: Thank you. I can't upvote due to being a new user (sucks) but I appreciate your answer!

Comment: that's ok. you can still "accept" the answer if it helped you - and that will earn you rep as well.

Comment: Great, I'll accept as soon as it lets me, I guess you gotta wait

Comment: btw, for a new user, this is a remarkably well explained question, with just the right amount of info needed to solve it.  kudos